# How to rename bluetooth devices on windows, persisting after reboot

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, rename

I have multiple bluetooth headsets of the same model but for different purposes.  I want them to appear with different names in the Windows panels for showing paired devices.  On Android it's easy to rename each device so I can tell which one I'm connected to.  How can I do this on Windows, and have it survive rebooting Windows?

There are many answers on the web, involving using "Devices and Printers" setting panel (I can get there from "Bluetooth & other devices" settings page; there may be other ways to get there.)  That works, but only until I reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue. The following solution has worked for me:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Go to Devices and Printers
3. Right Click on the device you want to change the name of and select properties
4. Click the Bluetooth Tab
5. Change the name to whatever you want
6. Click Okay and close the window
7. Right click on the device again and click "Remove Device"
8. Pair your device to your computer again
9. At this point, in the device selection window it should show the new device name that you just chose
10. If it does not show your new device name that you picked then it didn't work.
11. If it DID show the name you picked then finish the pairing and connect to your device. Go to settings and bluetooth and make sure the name is still changed
12. If the device still has the new name, restart the computer and after booting, check the device name again to make sure it stuck.
13. If the device name is still changed then congrats, it worked.
14. Now do this with every device you want to change the name of and it should work every time.

It works every time for me and I have had zero issues. So I hope it works for you as well.

Just remember, after changing the name, in order to get it to stick, you need to remove the device from your computer and pair with it again. That alone should make the name change permanently.

Good luck

Comment: Important: Step 0: Disconnect or power off the device.  (Step 6 won't save the new name if the device is connected.)

Comment: Also, it took me a moment to realize that `Control Panel` is NOT `Setup` .

Comment: I used this method in Windows 10 and it worked.  After upgrade to Windows 11 the edited name remains, which is good.  But I haven't tried to do this in Win11.  Most likely it'll still work.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows10 : Goto Start>Settings>About>Rename this Pc (After rename restart it). Mostly Pc Name is reflect to Bluetooth name

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that doesn't answer my question.  I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same issue. Did you get an answer to this?
From what I researched, this may not be possible at all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1157737)

Comment: Priyesh, welcome to Stack Overflow.  I realize it's frustrating when first joining that you can't make a comment.  But please don't use Answer to post a comment or question (your post will be deleted as it's not appropriate.)  But the answer is yes, the above selected answer worked.  Be sure to read my comments at the bottom before trying it.

Meanwhile, browse around for other posts that you can upvote or answer, and you'll quickly have enough points to post comments.