# Change Bluetooth Name in Windows 11 (Version 22H2 and higher)

Tags: bluetooth, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

I have two Bluetooth headsets (same model) that show up under the same name in Windows 11 (Version 22H2).

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change on the device itself (via a management tool), and my old solutions [here@superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1541655/how-to-rename-bluetooth-devices-on-windows-persisting-after-reboot) or [here@www](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/rename-bluetooth-device-windows-11/) for changing Bluetooth devices in Windows do not work anymore since the control panel page for devices (`control /name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters` or `control printers`) is replaced by the windows settings page. And I could find any new ones that work for Win11 22H2.

I'm looking for a solution to rename them in order to tell them apart.

Sidenote 1: at least I managed to rename them through the soundsettings (`ms-settings:sound`), but that doesn't have any effect on the Bluetooth name

Sidenote 2: The headset also has a USB-Dongle option, same problem there but I might just post a separate question for renaming USB devices

Comment: Not sure they added such feature however I wrote a small tool that does what you need. The tool uses Bluetooth Framework and can be download by this link: https://github.com/btframework/BtDeviceRenamer   There is full sources + excutable in bin\release folder.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks, I'll give it a try when I get a chance.